# The accept method of the ServerSocket class

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, serversocket

Apparently, it returns a Socket object. Is this the socket of the client that is trying to connect/ is connected to the ServerSocket object?

Also, does this method accept one connection from the client at a time or many?

Comment: post the code you are using and write the problem you are facing in the code.

Comment: I'm just asking about the working of the method that can't really understand fully from the oracle docs. Why do you need my code? I don't have any anyway.

Comment: What part of the Javadoc don't you understand? Your second question is certainly answered there,

Comment: @JanChrbolka "It" is clearly 'the `accept()` method of the `ServerSocket` class' as per the title. I don't think this is such a mystery.

Answer (score 4):

In order to accept an incoming client connection you must call the `ServerSocket.accept()` method.

The `accept()` method returns a Socket which is actually created for a specific client(the client which requested for connection),thus a Java for-Client `Socket` (residing on Server),not a Client-socket.Client's socket resides on Client's side which is used for starting communication. Here is how it works:

Server-side socket(but, distinct connection for each client based on threads) for establishing communication :-

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);    
boolean isStopped = false;
while(!isStopped){
    Socket clientBasedSocket = serverSocket.accept();  
    //do something with clientBasedSocket
}
```

Client-side socket :-

```
Socket s=new Socket("SERVER'S IP",9000);
```

Only one incoming connection is opened for each call to the accept() method.

As per Javadoc:

```
public Socket accept() throws IOException
```

> *Waits for an incoming client(request)*. This method blocks until either a client connects to the server on the specified
>   port or the socket times out, assuming that the time-out value has
>   been set using the setSoTimeout() method. Otherwise, this method
>   blocks indefinitely.

Comment: May I know why both of the answers have been downvoted? Please care to elaborate!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently, it returns a Socket object. Is this the socket of the client that is trying to connect/ is connected to the ServerSocket object?

No, it is a *new* `Socket` object that represents *this endpoint* of that connection. The client's socket represents the other endpoint.

> does this method accept one connection from the client at a time or many?

One at a time. Strange question. It returns one socket for one connection.

Comment: May I know why both of the answers have been downvoted? Please care to elaborate!!! @EJP- I upvoted yours(+1).

Comment: @shekharsuman Thanks, reciprocated. Some idiot seems to be about lately, see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29997236/207421).

Comment: @EJP- It seems someone has to raise this issue on [Meta SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), else downvoter won't stop this dumb act!

Comment: @JanChrbolka-Well, you need to find that OP's name is "Ross Taylor", & also a smart answer deserves an upvote from my side. Why do you have problem seeing this? Are you that downvoter,Just asking?

Comment: @shekharsuman Feel free. I can't bothered with this sort of nonsense myself. I've had a mystery daily downvote almost every day for quite some time now. Possibly someone is carefully rationing himself to one DV per person per day for the rest of his life. It's of no interest to me.